# Big difference in postgresql cluster size after upgrade from 9.4 to 9.5

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I've just upgraded a postgresql-9.4 cluster to 9.5. First, I installed 9.4 following:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/765539/how-to-install-postgresql-9-4-on-ubuntu-16-04

and then, I used

```
pg_upgradecluster 9.4 main
```

everything seems to be working fine with the new cluster. However, I find surprising the difference in size of the two clusters (from du -sch):

```
1,9G    9.4
2,5G    9.5
```

Using postgresql's command

```
\l+
```

in the 9.5 cluster, and adding sizes, it amounts to around 1.72 GiB, while the same procedure in the 9.4 cluster adds up to 1.70 GiB, almost the same.

To verify, I made a dump of the 9.4 cluster with

```
pg_dumpall > 9.4.dump
```

and then restored it in a clean 9.5 cluster with

```
cat 9.4.dump | psql
```

The restored cluster's size according to du is now 2.7 GB, similar to the previous one.

It seems a huge increment in disk usage for just an upgrade. Perhaps I am missing something? Is this how it is supposed to be?

**I mean, the 9.5 cluster is around 42% bigger than the 9.4 one with the same data.**

I don't know if this is the right forum for this kind of question, though I saw others related to postgresql install and upgrade.

Regards.

Comment: Have you issued any `vacuum` or `vacuum full` commands since the upgrade? It's possible that's just dead space from the upgrade. Also note that you can `select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(tablename));` to see the size of individual tables and their indices.

Comment: `du` shows the size of file/directory, not of the database - check with `pg_size_pretty` as @jmelesky said

Comment: I am concerned precisely with disk usage, and this case in which postgresql 9.5 needs 2.5 GB to store what postgresql 9.4 does in 1.9 GB. I edited the question to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: That certainly is rather unusual. If anything 9.5 should need less room. Can you drill down to identify what exactly has grown.

Comment: Edited again, with more info. My next test is going to be restoring a dump and comparing.

Comment: 9.5's default configuration allows the space for WAL files to grow (much) bigger then the default configuration for 9.4. Did you check if `pg_xlog` takes that additional space?

Comment: Can you show us the size of each sub-directory in the data directory (`base`, `global`, `pg_log`, `pg_xlog` and so on, e.g. by using `du --max-depth=1 -h`) to determine which part is using the space

Comment: That's right, @a-horse-with-no-name! It was pg_xlog, I didn't know what you meant in the first comment. Then I realized it was a directory. If you want to post an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!